# Form Validation IE7

Tags: javascript, validation, internet-explorer-7

I've created a form that submits and works correctly everywhere I've tested except when I'm using IE7 (IE8 may have the problem as well I don't have a machine to test that with.)

When I try IE7 the form will not submit and the JavaScript validation also does not function. I believe the issue is a difference the way JavaScript works but so far everything I've tested has made no difference.

HTML

```
<form id="find_agent" action="find_agent_form_processor.asp" onsubmit="return validateAgentForm();" method="POST">
<fieldset>
    <ul id="find_agent_errors">
        <li id="find_agent_first_name_error">Please Enter Your First Name</li>
        <li id="find_agent_last_name_error">Please Enter Your Last Name</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="hidden" name="To" value="you@domain.com" />
            <input type="hidden" name="From" value="me@domain.com" />
            <input type="hidden" name="Subject" value="Find Agent" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <strong>First Name: <span class="red_text">*</span></strong>
            <input type="text" name="find_agent_first_name">
        </li>
        <li>
            <strong>Last Name: <span class="red_text">*</span></strong>
            <input type="text" name="find_agent_last_name">
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function validateAgentForm(){
var count = 0;

var findAgentFirstName = document.forms["find_agent"]["find_agent_first_name"].value;
if(findAgentFirstName.length < 1){
    document.getElementById("find_agent_first_name_error").style.visibility = "visible";
    count++;
}
else{
    document.getElementById("find_agent_first_name_error").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
if(count > 0){
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Give the form a name, "find_agent" in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     function validateAgentForm(){
        var count = 0;
        var findAgentFirstName = document.forms["find_agent"]["find_agent_first_name"].value;
        if(findAgentFirstName.length < 1){
            document.getElementById("find_agent_first_name_error").style.visibility = "visible";
            count++;
return false;//This will prevent the form from submitting if the text field is empty
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("find_agent_first_name_error").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        }
```

Comment: That should be handled. I'm using the count variable for that but I forgot to include that section of code originally.